# Does cron queue manage max_execution time?

Tags: 7, cron

I have implemented an approximately 1000 nodes update using `hook_cron_queue_info()` and `hook_cron()`. When I manually run cron job from the Drupal administration pages, I get a *maximum time execution* error; once this number is reduced by 10, it works fine.

Any suggestion?

```
function my_module_cron_queue_info() {  
  $queues['my_module_batch'] = array(
    'worker callback' => '_my_module_process_queue',
    'skip on cron' => FALSE,
  );
  return $queues;
}


function my_module_cron() {
  $contents = lade_update_nodes(); // get node list for updation
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('my_module_batch');
  foreach ($contents as $p_file) {
    $process_data = array(
    // set values for process
    );
    $queue->createItem($process_data);
  }
}

function _my_module_process_queue($arr) {
    // code for updation
    watchdog('update node', 'Custom msg');
}
```

Comment: It's not completely clear; are you processing 1.000 nodes in one batch, or it's 1.000 nodes in total?

Comment: @Aram Boyajyan: I have added my code with post.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title, Drupal cron does check the time used to process the items in a queue, and by default it gives 15 seconds to each queue. This still doesn't avoid the total time given to all the queues doesn't exceed the limit, especially if the call to `drupal_set_time_limit(240)` (which would set the time limit to 240 seconds) doesn't have success.

Also, since the code used by Drupal is the following one (see [`drupal_cron_run()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7)), if processing a single item in a queue requires more than the time assigned to processing a queue (for example 30 seconds instead of 15), Drupal cannot block processing a queue when the time assigned to a queue is passed.

```
  foreach ($queues as $queue_name => $info) {
    if (!empty($info['skip on cron'])) {
      // Do not run if queue wants to skip.
      continue;
    }
    $callback = $info['worker callback'];
    $end = time() + (isset($info['time']) ? $info['time'] : 15);
    $queue = DrupalQueue::get($queue_name);
    while (time() < $end && ($item = $queue->claimItem())) {
      try {
        call_user_func($callback, $item->data);
        $queue->deleteItem($item);
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
        // In case of exception log it and leave the item in the queue
        // to be processed again later.
        watchdog_exception('cron', $e);
      }
    }
  }
```

If you get a *maximum time execution* error, you can just limit the number of processed items, or assign less time for your queue.

```
function my_module_cron_queue_info() {  
  $queues['my_module_batch'] = array(
    'worker callback' => '_my_module_process_queue',
    'time' => 3,
  );
  return $queues;
}
```

As side note, setting `'skip on cron'` to `FALSE` is useless, as Drupal assumes it is `FALSE` by default. In fact, it uses `if (!empty($info['skip on cron'])) {}` to decide if skipping a queue; `!empty($info['skip on cron'])` is `FALSE` when `$info['skip on cron']` is not set, or when it is set to `FALSE`.